# Cucumber report attachment - json format - XRay Jira API

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, jira, cucumber-jvm, jira-xray

I am currently implementing integration of Cucumber/Jira/Xray. I am using json formatter plugin from cucumber to generate test report and xray maven plugin to import test result in Jira/Xray. See code below:

```
@ConfigurationParameter(
    key = "cucumber.plugin",
    value = "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json"
)
public class RunnerPttas {
}
```

Things are working fine as long as I don't have any attachments which I want to attach to test executions in Jira. I am using following code to attach screenshots to the scenario:

```
@AfterStep
    public void takeScreenshots(Scenario scenario) throws IOException {
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(screenshotPath+"evidence.png"));;// get screenshot from somewhere
        scenario.attach(data, "image/png", "Evidence");
    }
```

Now I see the screenshot is added to the after object inside each step in the scenario like below:

```
[
  {
    "elements": [
      {
        ...
        "steps": [
          {
            ...
            "after": [
              {
                "embeddings": [
                  {
                    "data": "<BASE64_ENCODED_FILE>"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now checking at the official [xray documentation](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY32/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST#ImportExecutionResultsREST-CucumberJSONresultsMultipart), the attachment needs to come under step object directly (and not wrapped inside `after` object), see below:

```
[
  {
    "elements": [
      {
        ...
        "steps": [
          {
            ...
            "embeddings": [
              {
                "data": "<BASE64_ENCODED_FILE>"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is it something I could configure the json formatter plugin to produce the right format? Currently imported results do not show any attachment in the Jira Test Execution ticket. I believe its not an xray maven plugin issue, its just the format produced is not correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Attachments are supported at scenario level hooks or at step level hooks.
Therefore, the following format is fine

```
 "elements": [
  {
    "steps": [
      {
        "result": {
          "duration": 440463000,
          "status": "passed"
        },
        "line": 6,
        "name": "user is on the welcome page",
        "match": {
          "location": "webdemo.StepDefinitions.user_is_on_the_welcome_page()"
        },
        "after": [
          {
            "embeddings": [
              {
                "data": "iVBOR...
```

After importing the results you should have something like this:
[Xray datacenter screenshot with evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKdwU.png)

Please not that the attachments are seen on the Test Run execution details page; maybe that's your issue in fact. To go there, you need to use that shortcut available from the Test Execution page, next to the corresponding Test.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDTHZ.png)

In this case I'm using this to run the tests:

`mvn clean compile test -Dcucumber.plugin="json:report.json" -Dcucumber.features="features/"`

I have here a [full working example](https://github.com/Xray-App/tutorial-java-cucumber-selenium).
I've [updated it](https://github.com/Xray-App/tutorial-java-cucumber-selenium/blob/main/src/test/java/webdemo/StepDefinitions.java) with a code snippet of the `@AfterStep` hook.

Note: This works both for Xray on Jira server/datacenter or Xray on Jira cloud.